# SetTimeOut not working in React Native if we starting app from fragment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fragment

I am integrating react-native in my existing android app. I am having one fragment and from that fragment, I am starting the React Native Module.
Here is the code for starting module from Android Fragment.

```
 @Override
    public ReactRootView onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        SoLoader.init(getActivity(), /**/ false);
ReactRootView mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(getActivity());
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getActivity().getApplication())
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .addPackage(new RNGestureHandlerPackage())
                .addPackage(new RNDeviceInfo())
                .addPackage(new ReactCallbackManagerPackage(this))
                .addPackage(new ReanimatedPackage())
                .addPackage(new VectorIconsPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.BEFORE_CREATE)
                .build();
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "reactnativemodule", initialProps);
}
```

Everything is working fine except

```
setTimeout(function () {
            data.events = [];
            resolvePreInitHooks();
            resolve();
          }, 1000);
```

is not calling. `SetTimeOut` code should execute after 1 second but it is not executing.